# Enforce no-root-logger policy for Python

Tags: python, logging

I work on an open source project, and in the project we used to allow all modules to log on the root logger:

```
import logging


def my_function():
  logging.info('Logging something on the root- logger')
```

We're moving to use per-module loggers, like so:

```
import logging

_LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def my_function():
  _LOGGER.info('Logging something on the root- logger')
```

Is there a way to enforce this policy via Linter / Static checks, so that others will not log on the root logger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is definitely not possible with static checking if you want to find all cases where that happens. The best you can achieve is basically looking for the string `logging.[info|debug|...]` in the source.  A static checker is easily fooled by something like this:

```
logger_name = 'root' # might even read this from a config file
_LOGGER = logging.getLogger(logger_name) # static check has no way to know here that we get the root logger 
_LOGGER.info('logging this to root')
```

Besides that, if you don't set `propagate` to false on your module level loggers they still propagate their logs to the root logger.

Comment: fair enough. I figured it was unlikely, but worth a try. Thanks!